# Questions about an atmega32 serial-bus to RS232 with converter and different logic levels

Tags: atmega, rs232, max232, serial-bus, max3232

I have an atmega32 and a FUM DCF-U atomic clock (signal receiver and decoder) of [HKW-elektronik](http://www.hkw-elektronik.de/). The µ-controller works with 5V and the module on 3.3V.

I have to build a converter, because the µ-controller only has serial-bus communication and the module has RS232 communication.

I did some research and I found these IC's: [MAX232](http://sk.fotoarchiefje.nl/Datasheets/max232.pdf), [MAX3323E](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3322E-MAX3323E.pdf) or [MAX3232](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf).
In the datasheets and on [ArduinoSoftwareRS232](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoSoftwareRS232) reads that it needs extra voltages (one + and one -) for some pins. Is this necessary or are the capacitors enough?
And which IC should I use? (First time I need to use these IC's)

And can these IC's being used without a logic voltage converter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use the MAX232, and 4 0.1milifarad ceramic capacitors. It works fine for my uses.

Comment: In the datasheet in figure 4. You have to put 8.5V on the 2 and 6 pins. Is this necessary? And do I need a logic level controller between the converter (attached to the µ-controller, 5V) and receiver (3.3V)?

Comment: (I use 1microfarad and not 0.1mili as i mentioned above) I dont connect 8.5V to those pins. Just the capacitors, which are connected to the ground as well. My Vcc is connected directly to 5V without a capacitor there. Though i do have a decoupling capacitor between vcc and the common ground.

Comment: This is very helpfull. Now my module uses 3.3V for VCC. Is this a problem for the RS232 communication voltage levels?

Comment: MAX232 is used to convert TTL voltage levels into RS232 ones. TTL means 5v and 0v, and my RS232 are -9v and +9v. The MAX232 "flips" and amplifies voltage levels. But im not a big expert, so il suggest you will wait for others to say their opinions.

Comment: I'm going to order the MAX232 and see if it's good enough for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Answer has been given by Eminem, see his comments below:

**Eminem**

I use the MAX232, and 4 0.1milifarad ceramic capacitors. It works fine for my uses.

**Me**

In the datasheet in figure 4. You have to put 8.5V on the 2 and 6 pins. Is this necessary? And do I need a logic level controller between the converter (attached to the µ-controller, 5V) and receiver (3.3V)?

**Eminem**

(I use 1microfarad and not 0.1mili as i mentioned above) I dont connect 8.5V to those pins. Just the capacitors, which are connected to the ground as well. My Vcc is connected directly to 5V without a capacitor there. Though i do have a decoupling capacitor between vcc and the common ground.

**Me**

This is very helpfull. Now my module uses 3.3V for VCC. Is this a problem for the RS232 communication voltage levels?

**Eminem**

MAX232 is used to convert TTL voltage levels into RS232 ones. TTL means 5v and 0v, and my RS232 are -9v and +9v. The MAX232 "flips" and amplifies voltage levels. But im not a big expert, so il suggest you will wait for others to say their opinions.